# How write complicated macro function without GCC parenthesis extension?

Tags: c, function, macros

How can I write my division and multiplication functions as macro without GCC parenthesis extension?

I want it to be cross-platform and I don't want to use inline function as it wouldn't make compiler to embed translated codes in whole compiled file.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long double division(long double num1, long double num2) {

    long double count = 0.0, count2 = 0.0, remain = 0.0;
    while (num1 > 0) {
        if (num1 < num2)
            break;
        num1 = num1 - num2;
        count++;
    }
    if (num1 != 0)
        remain = num1;
    long double remain2 = remain;
    while (remain2 > 0) {
        int c = 1000000;
        long double one = 0.0;
        while (c > 1) {
            remain = remain2;
            remain2 = 0.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                remain2 = remain2 + remain;
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < c; k++) {
                one = one + 0.0000001;
            }
            while (remain2 > 0) {
                if (remain2 < num2)
                    break;
                remain2 = remain2 - num2;
                count2 = count2 + one;
            }
            one = 0.0;
            c = division(c, 10);
        }
        if (remain2 != 0)
            break;
    }
    if (num1 == 0)
        return count;
    else
        return (count + count2);
}

long double mult(long double num1, long double num2) {
    int integer1 = num1, integer2 = num2;
    long double fraction1 = 0.0, fraction2 = 0.0;
    fraction1 = num1 - integer1;
    fraction2 = num2 - integer2;
    int result1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < integer1; i++) {
        result1 = result1 + num2;
    }
    long double result2 = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < integer1; j++) {
        result2 = result2 + fraction2;
    }
    long double result3 = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < integer2; k++) {
        result3 = result3 + fraction1;
    }
    long double result4 = 0.0;
    if (fraction2 > 0.0)
        result4 = division(fraction1, (division(1, fraction2)));
    else
        result4 = 0.0;
    long double result = result1 + result2 + result3 + result4;

    return result;
}

long double powerinteger(long double num1, long double num2) {
    int integer = num2;
    long double result = 1.0;
    for (int j = 0; j < integer; j++) {
        result = mult(result, num1);
    }
    return result;
}

long double power(long double num1, long double num2) {
    int integer = num2;
    long double fraction = (num2 + 0.01) - integer;
    fraction = mult(fraction, 10000);
    long double powerednum = 0.0, assistant = 0.0, result = 1.01;
    powerednum = powerinteger(num1, division(fraction, 1000));
    assistant = powerednum;
    while (assistant > 1) {
        int i = 0;
        while ((assistant >= 1) && (i < 10)) {
            assistant = division(assistant, result);
            if (assistant <= 1.000001)
                break;
            i++;
        }
        if (assistant > 1.00001) {
            result = result + 0.01;
            assistant = powerednum;
        } else
            break;
    }

    return mult(result, (powerinteger(num1, num2)));
}

long double check(long double num) {
    while (num >= 0) {
        num = num - 2;
    }

    if (num < 1)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

int main() {
    printf("Enter 2 numbers to get power :\n");
    long double a = 0.0, b = 0.0;
    scanf("%Lf%Lf", &a, &b);
    if ((a > 0) && (b > 0))
        printf("Your result is : %Lf\n", power(a, b));
    else if ((a == 0) && (b > 0))
        printf("0\n");
    else if ((a == 0) && (b == 0))
        printf("Indeterminable!\n");
    else if (((a > 0) || (a < 0)) && (b == 0))
        printf("1\n");
    else if ((a > 0) && (b < 0))
        printf("Your result is : %Lf\n", division(1, power(a, fabs(b))));
    else if ((a < 0) && (b > 0)) {
        if ((check(fabs(b)) == 0))
            printf("Your result is : -%Lf\n", power(fabs(a), b));
        else
            printf("Your result is : -%Lf\n", division(1, power(a, fabs(b))));
    } else
    if ((a < 0) && (b < 0)) {
        if ((check(fabs(b)) == 0))
            printf("Your result is : %Lf\n", division(1, power(fabs(a), fabs(b))));
        else
            printf("Your result is : -%Lf\n", division(1, power(fabs(a), fabs(b))));
    } else
        printf("Undefined!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I want to speed up my code but with inline function it doesn't because the codes must embed in the whole code and GCC extension works but I want to write it as cross-platform code. Thanks a lot

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by writing these as macros?

Comment: What is the macro you're trying to write? What do you mean by "GCC parenthesis extension"?

Comment: These functions are so long and complex that the function call overhead will be negligible. Turning them into macros will not make any significant difference, and could even make thing worse because of the code bloat.

Comment: You don't want a macro, you want `__attribute__((always_inline))`. But measure if it actually makes the code faster or not.

Comment: @Barmar: They meant [the GCC statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).

Comment: @ScottHunter I wrote in caption , macros get replaced and I think it will make the code faster

Answer (score 0):

Just like https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar mentioned, turning them into macros will almost certainly make them slower.

You have too many red flags:

1. Why write primitive operations in custom code in the first place?
2. Why so worried about performance?

Optimization is almost always a waste of time. There's always bound to be dozens of stuff to do for a project that are 10x+ more important. And whatever rationale you have can wait until this code is used heavily in production.

To give you a bit of perspective, projects can be 10+ years-old and still don't optimize the majority of their performance-sensitive code. And that's one reason why they got to be 10+ years old. The best, most perfect code is dead-projects code.

And what most programmers don't know is that optimization is entirely different from what they think and, if not done correctly, it's much more likely to make a product/project slower.

Comment: Actually, most of any code is dead projects code.

Comment: Hello Sir , I can expand the code to run fast , But I'm teaching " Function " subject in my book and I said may be there would be a way to write it as it still be a function

Comment: The code seems unnecessarily complex. And you should write comments to justify this complexity so the reader can either understand or present you with possible alternatives.